# sql запрос для вывода информации из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Только начал изучать, прошу понять и простить. Уже всю голову сломал.

*Нужно вывести money, certificates из users и id из user_sessions для пользователей, у которых дата обновления сессии(updated_at) была раньше 25 мая 2021.*

Две таблицы, **users**:
[image: users]

**user_sessions**:

[image: user_sessions]

Идея была найти максимальное значение в колонке updated_at для каждого пользователя и сравнить его с '20210525', но этот максимум я так и не смог получить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
    SELECT users.money, users.certificates, user_sessions.id FROM users, user_sessions 
    WHERE users.id=user_sessions.user_id AND user_sessions.updated_at<'2021-05-25'
```

(я писал из головы, ничго не проверяя, вполне возможно, по условиям задачи надо будет в запросе еще что то подкрутить).

На самом деле, это прямой перевод фразы "вывести money, certificates из users и id из user_sessions для пользователей, у которых дата обновления сессии(updated_at) была раньше 25 мая 2021" на SQL'ный

PS. После уточнения условия в комментариях предлагаю такой вариант:

```
    SELECT users.money, users.certificates, user_sessions.id FROM users, user_sessions 
    WHERE users.id=user_sessions.user_id AND user_sessions.updated_at<'2021-05-25' AND
    user_sessions.user_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_sessions.user_id FROM user_sessions WHERE user_sessions.updated_at>='2021-05-25')
```

ТО есть, я добавил подзапрос `SELECT DISTINCT user_sessions.user_id FROM user_sessions WHERE user_sessions.updated_at>='2021-05-25'` Этот запрос должен найти id шники всех пользователй, котрые логинились в систему позже даты, и по этим Id мы исключим строки из вывода первоначального запроса

Comment: Был мой первый вариант, только с использованием JOIN. Увы, неправильный. Получается, что мы тут смотрим, где есть дата меньше, чем 2021-05-25 и все это выводим. Однако, у этого же юзера она может быть и больше. А нам нужны только те юзеры, у которых последняя сессия была не позднее 2021-05-25, т.е. раньше этой даты.

Comment: А, я понял. То есть, тех пользоватеелй, у котрых были сессии позднее указанной даты, надо из запроса исключить... Вот в это то я по формулировке задачи вообще не врубился. Сейчас подправлю

Comment: Спасибо, пока оставлю это как ответ. Вероятно, позже вернусь с пояснениями.